# Send Push Notification to Multiple User with Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I want to use cloud function to detect the automatic changes in Firestore database collection and send a notification to users.

App has an option to add the question when User A adds a question all other users get a notification like "User A Added Question to Place".
Attached Images of my Firestore database to understand.

[image]

when the user posts a question we can get author uid "addedBy" from the above-shown document.

and by uid we can get FCM token and name etc from user collection which I show below.

[image]

I have setup index.js file and test a single user notification with changing in the database, but I need to know which logic I should use for this requirement and my app based on Swift.

**Edit:**

I have this progress so far now get user token list and want to compare this list with author token and exclude author token and sent a push notification to remaining users.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { UserDimensions } = require('firebase-functions/lib/providers/analytics');
const { firebaseConfig } = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

var db = admin.firestore();


exports.sendQuestionPushNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('placeQuestions/{userId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
        let questionID = context.params.userId;
        console.log('Question ID:', questionID);
        let questionAuthorId = change.after.data().addeddBy;
        console.log('Author ID:', questionAuthorId);
        let placeID = change.after.data().addedToPlace;
        console.log('Place ID:', placeID);

        
   var userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(questionAuthorId);
   return userRef
     .get()
     .then(doc => {
       if (!doc.exists) {
         console.log('No such User document!');
         throw new Error('No such User document!');
       } else {
         const authorName = doc.data().name;
         const authorToken = doc.data().fcmToken;
         console.log('Auhtor Name: ', authorName);
         console.log('Author Token: ', authorToken);

        return firestore.collection('mapPlaces').doc(placeID).get();
       }
     })
     .then((result) => {
      if (!result.exists) {
        console.log('No such Place document!');
        throw new Error('No such Place document!');
      } else {
        const placeName = result.data().name;
        console.log('Place Name: ', placeName)
        return firestore.collection('users').get();
      }
     })
     .then((userList) => {
       userList.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user.id, '=>', user.data().fcmToken);
       });
       return true;
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log('Error getting data', err);
       return false;
     });
    });
```

Comment: [Google Cloud Functions For Firebase triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#function_triggers) listen for changes in your database and you can implement the logic to notify your users. The above documentation will help you get started. Give it a try and please post your code to explain where you got stuck and what it is that isn't working the way you expect. Also, GCF supports multiple language runtimes (Swift is not), and Firebase only provides tools and SDKs for Node.js right now.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I figure it out and write some code now I get question author data, place data, etc, and get a token list with help of forEach, now im stuck, 
next step will be, 

compare token array with the author token and exclude author token from the array, and send a notification to remaining tokens,

i am updating my question with code which i wrote.

Comment: If you want to compare _authorToken_ with the _userToken_, you can use a [compound query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) to make this comparison and retrieve only the users that you want to send the notifications to based on the _authorToken_. Let me know if this works.